# Narrowing down the function argument type in class implementing protocol

Tags: swift, generics, existential-type

I have a protocol for simple http client:

```
protocol HttpClientProtocol {
    func request(route: any RouteProtocol)
}

protocol RouteProtocol {
    associatedtype T : Encodable //this is probably irrelevant, but nevertheless
    // ...stuff
}
```

Now, I'm trying to use this protocol as a type that will be used by clients (e.g. some `MyThingRepository` will inject `HttpClientProtocol` without knowing the specific type that will be injected - for loose coupling). Then I'm trying to create a concrete class from that protocol.

```
class ApiClient : HttpClientProtocol {
    
    
    func request(route: any ApiRouteProtocol) {
        //... use specific ApiRouteProtocol here, not the general RouteProtocol
    }
    
}

protocol ApiRouteProtocol : RouteProtocol, URLRequestConvertible { }
```

Problem is that I get `Type 'ApiClient' does not conform to protocol 'HttpClientProtocol'` compilation error.

My intuition is that if the protocol allows `any RouteProtocol`, then the class implementing it should be able to narrow down the type to `ApiRouteProtocol`. However, the compiler doesn't agree. Is my intuition wrong or is it a Swift limitation?

What could I do to work around it? My only working idea for now is to force cast the `route` to `ApiRouteProtocol` in `ApiClient`.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*

For external access from another module where you can't use an extension I believe the only solution is to declare the functions as it is defined in the protocol and then internally check for the correct conformance

```
class ApiClient : HttpClientProtocol {
    func request(route: any RouteProtocol) {
        guard let route = route as? (any ApiRouteProtocol) else {
            return // or some error handling
        }
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

---

*Old solution*

One solution is to conform to the protocol but make use of polymorphism to handle calls using `ApiRouteProtocol`. Not a perfect solution but it works since for any route object that conforms to `ApiRouteProtocol` the function in the extension will be called.

```
class ApiClient : HttpClientProtocol {

    func request(route: any RouteProtocol) {
        return // or whatever you want 
    }
}

extension ApiClient {
    func request(route: any ApiRouteProtocol) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, checked that and I might be doing sth wrong, but it doesn't seem to work. If I instantiate ApiClient and call on it directly, then the extension is invoked. But if my repository only knows about HttpClientProtocol, than it doesn't call the extension, even though I use ApiRouteProtocol in request. For that to work I would have to either inject the concrete type to repository or force cast inside the general function so we're back at the starting point.

Comment: If your repository only knows about the protocol then you need to solve this inside the implementation of `request(route: any RouteProtocol)` in ApiClient.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm working on. If I'm not mistaken, the whole design was wrong and I shouldn't have this ApiRouteProtocol at all. Will probably post an answer when I have the final snippet. Or you can edit yours and I could accept it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I overcomplicated things by introducing `ApiRouteProtocol`. I imagined I needed it to conform to `UrlRequestConvertible` in its extension, but the thing is that I can do a private extension to the `RouteProtocol` itself and
handle the specific implementation required by `ApiClient : HttpClientProtocol` there.

```
class ApiClient : HttpClientProtocol {
    
    func request(route: any RouteProtocol) {
        //...route.asURLRequest()...
    }
    
}

extension RouteProtocol {
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest { //...
}
```

And now my repository only knows about abstract `HttpClientProtocol` and `RouteProtocol` and has no interest in ApiClient and its internals which is what I was trying to achieve here.